# mysql query multiple params from one table?

Tags: mysql, search, select

Okay i have mysql query, and i'd like to search both parameters  in table_1
i'll try showing the idea with "php"

```
if(table_2_params.params_id == 124){
   //select LIKE  "%EXTEC (Sandvik)%" from  table_2_params.nosaukums
}
elseif(table_2_params.params_id == 126){
  //SELECT  FROM table_2_params WHERE nosaukums is BETWEEN  "2010" AND  "2012"
}
```

I want to query display first AND second parameter...(**both of them to match**) 
daymn i hope you will understand what i want to say...

Okay here's the
**mysql query:**

```
 SELECT table_1 . * , table_2_params . * 
    FROM table_1, table_2_params
    WHERE table_1.pamat_kat_sad =  '756'
    AND table_1.preces_id = table_2_params.preces_id
    AND (
        (
        table_2_params.params_id =124
        AND table_2_params.nosaukums LIKE  "%EXTEC (Sandvik)%"
        )
        AND (
        table_2_params.params_id =126
        AND table_2_params.nosaukums
        BETWEEN  "2010"
        AND  "2012"
        )
    )
    ORDER BY table_1.preces_id DESC
```

Problem might be that the `table_2_params.nosaukums` type is `longtext` ...

If i select only with

```
    AND (
    table_2_params.params_id =126
    AND table_2_params.nosaukums
    BETWEEN  "2010"
    AND  "2012"
    )
```

it displays correct year...
AND if i select only with

```
(
    table_2_params.params_id =124
    AND table_2_params.nosaukums LIKE  "%EXTEC (Sandvik)%"
    )
```

it also displays correct values...

But i cant make them both work together..

Please help me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two sets of conditions just use `OR`. You should also note that joins between tables should be performed using `(INNER|LEFT) JOIN` :

```
SELECT
    table_1.*
    , table_2_params.* 
FROM
    table_1
    INNER JOIN table_2_params
        ON table_1.preces_id = table_2_params.preces_id
WHERE
    table_1.pamat_kat_sad =  '756'
    AND
    (
        (
            table_2_params.params_id =124
            AND table_2_params.nosaukums LIKE '%EXTEC (Sandvik)%'
        )
        OR
        (
            table_2_params.params_id =126
            AND table_2_params.nosaukums BETWEEN '2010' AND '2012'
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    table_1.preces_id DESC
```

And finally your query may perform poorly, since mysql won't be able to use any index with `AND table_2_params.nosaukums LIKE '%EXTEC (Sandvik)%'`

Comment: but i want these two sets of conditions to match both... it should search 1 AND 2 ... both of them, not only one of them...

Comment: if you want 1 AND 2, you will always have an empty response, because `table_2_params.params_id =124` and `table_2_params.params_id =126` can't be true simultaneously. On the other hand, if you want the union of conditions, that's what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
 AND (
    (
    table_2_params.params_id =124          #remove this check
    AND table_2_params.nosaukums LIKE  "%EXTEC (Sandvik)%"
    )
    AND (
    table_2_params.params_id =126          #or remove this check
    AND table_2_params.nosaukums
    BETWEEN  "2010"
    AND  "2012"
    )
)
```

You try to compare if the params_id is both 124 and 126. That will never work. Remove one of those comparisons and your query should work! :)